# ROS fuerte on OSX fails on rxtools build

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, buiding-errors, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instrutions on http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

In the make step, after cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF

it stops at
[ 60%] Built target test_rosbag_genpy
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librxtools.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"wxRichTextCtrl::ms_classInfo", referenced from:
rxtools::TextboxDialog::onChar(wxKeyEvent&) in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
"wxRichTextCtrl::wxRichTextCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)", referenced from:
rxtools::TextboxDialog::TextboxDialog(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long) in rosout_generated.cpp.o
"wxRichTextBuffer::BeginTextColour(wxColour const&)", referenced from:
wxRichTextCtrl::BeginTextColour(wxColour const&) in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
"wxRichTextBuffer::BeginBold()", referenced from:
wxRichTextCtrl::BeginBold() in rosout_list_control.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/librxtools.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

All previous steps has been followed without errors. Is there anything I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46028/ros-fuerte-on-osx-fails-on-rxtools-build/) by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

reinstalling wxPython and using the latest version, instead of the one linked to in the guide solved the problem. This is just a note to others having the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) with karma: 43 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) on 2012-10-18**:
I can't accept my own answer as the correct answer, becuase my karma is too low. So if anyone with enough karma could close the question, so it won't show in the unanswered list?